# Would the windows.old folder contain the old pagefile?

Tags: windows, reset, pagefile

I understand the windows.old contains user data and some other files, but does it contain the pagefile? As in the pagefile prior to a reset/update.

Comment: No; It doesn’t; Why do you need the page file? You can’t restore anything from it.

Comment: No. Pagefile is about running state, not offline state. the only reason its on disk when the system is off is because it would take a lot of effort to create/destroy it at every boot. its generally a large file, so when the Os uses it, it uses indexed operations to touch only the little bit of the file it cares about at any given second, so often much of its content is meaningless and ignored (because the particular page in questing is not mapped to a running process. recreating and destroying it is therefore unnecessary.

Comment: It might be worth your while to study page files and you would know then that they would not be saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the pagefile is not backed up into the .old folder during the system upgrade process.